# Update column with count of row value in another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have no idea why I haven't found a solution to this on here but: I am trying to `COUNT` how many times the `Serial_Parent` appears during the packing phase so I can use this in other calculations.

This works perfectly:

```
SELECT 
    Serial_Parent, COUNT(Serial_Parent)
FROM 
    mfng_data
WHERE 
    Machine_Process = 'Packing'
GROUP BY 
    Serial_Parent;
```

However when I try to `UPDATE` a column with this `COUNT`, I fail miserably as it just counts all the rows in the table and saves that as each row value thus 2,134,222 appearing in each row value.

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE mfng_data
SET Count_Serial_Parent = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM mfng_data 
                           WHERE Machine_Process = 'Packing'
                             AND Serial_Parent = Serial_Parent) 
WHERE Serial_Parent = Serial_Parent;
```

I've also tried this:

```
UPDATE mfng_data
SET Count_Serial_Parent = (SELECT COUNT(Serial_Parent)
                           FROM mfng_data 
                           WHERE Machine_Process = 'Packing'
                             AND Serial_Parent = Serial_Parent);
```

Sample data:

```
Spec: 12373  Rev: -6    M35846  M358461 M3584610    M35846101   NULL    NULL    NULL    M35846101   6808
Spec: 12373  Rev: -6    M35846  M358461 M3584610    M35846102   NULL    NULL    NULL    M35846102   6808
Spec: 16692  Rev: -4    K45678  K456781 K4567810    K45678101   NULL    NULL    NULL    K45678101   3964
Spec: 16692  Rev: -4    K45678  K456782 K4567820    K45678201   NULL    NULL    NULL    K45678201   3978
Spec: 16693  Rev: -4    K45678  K456782 K4567820    K45678202   NULL    NULL    NULL    K45678202   3806
```

Desired result (M35846 will appear twice so it will list "2" for each row entry)

```
Serial_Parent Count_Serial_Parent
----------------------------------
M35846           2
M35846           2
J39384          52 - - > 52 rows will show "52" and so on below
M35488          10
K4448            4
M35927           8
K45678           3
```

Comment: your where clause  WHERE Serial_Parent = Serial_Parent; is true for each row, so every row is updated. the second attempt has no where clause so by default all are updated.  Which rows should be updated?  Can you post some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.  I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need table aliases and qualified column names:

```
UPDATE m
    SET Count_Serial_Parent = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                               FROM mfng_data m2
                               WHERE m2.Machine_Process = 'Packing' AND
                                     m2.Serial_Parent = m.Serial_Parent 
                              )
    FROM mfng_data m;
```

The subquery needs to be *correlated* to the outer query.  A condition such as `Serial_Parent = Serial_Parent` basically always evaluates to true because it is referring to the column of the table referenced in the subquery.

However, the better approach is an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select m.*,
             sum(case when m.Machine_Process = 'Packing' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by m.serial_parent) as new_Count_Serial_Parent 
      from  mfng_data m
     )
update toupdate
    set Count_Serial_Parent = new_Count_Serial_Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (using a toy table -- hope you get the idea):

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (Serial_Parent int, Count_Serial_Parent int)
INSERT INTO @ (Serial_Parent, Count_Serial_Parent) VALUES
(1,0), (1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0)
SELECT * FROM @

UPDATE m -- mfng_data

SET m.Count_Serial_Parent = j.Count_Serial_Parent
FROM @ m -- mfng_data
JOIN (
SELECT Serial_Parent, COUNT(*) Count_Serial_Parent
FROM @ 
GROUP BY Serial_Parent
) j ON j.Serial_Parent = m.Serial_Parent

SELECT * FROM @
```